# Animate button below specific div using jquery

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-animate

There are 3 buttons centered under a div (with margin-top value).
After the user click on one of them it should be animated and move below the div.
I succeed to do it only for the first button.

Example is here [Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fribroon/xe31uvnj/)

The problem is that the second button (when choosed) is moving below the first button (eventhough I removed the "non-choosed" buttons before animation has started.

HTML:

```
<body>
  <div id="inner_body">
    <div>
      Animate button below me!
    </div>
    <button class="bc" id="0" style="margin-top:250px">Botton A</button>
    <button class="bc" id="1">Botton B</button>
    <button class="bc" id="2">Botton C is below buton A and button B</button>
  </div>
</body>
```

JavaSctipt:

```
$(document).on('click', '.bc', function() {
  var x = [];
  var y = [];
  //Saving original position
  for (var i = 0; i < 3; i = i + 1) {
    x[i] = $('#' + i + '').position().left;
    y[i] = $('#' + i + '').position().top;
  }

  //Locating all buttons with absolute position
  for (var i = 0; i < 3; i = i + 1) {
    $('#' + i + '').css({
      'position': 'absolute',
      'top': y[i] + 'px',
      'left': x[i] + 'px'
    })
  }

  //Hiding other buttons
  for (var i = 0; i < 3; i = i + 1) {
    if (i != this.id) {
      $('#' + i + '').remove();
    }
  }

  //Animating our buttons
  $(this).animate({
    left: 0,
    marginTop: 0
  }, "slow");

});
```

CSS:

```
    #inner_body {
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 50px
}

button {
  margin-right: 40px;
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: #718bf3;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to use `top : 0,` and `marginTop : height of the div`

```
//Animating our buttons
  $(this).animate({
    left: 0,
    top: 0,
    marginTop: $('#inner_body > div').outerHeight()
  }, "slow");
```

[**Jsfiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/mohamedyousef1980/xe31uvnj/4/)

Comment: Nice! in the example there is only one div in the page. In my application there are several divs and other content above the buttons. Can I calcultae the height between this div and the top of the container?

Comment: Thank you very much - this is what I looked for.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<body>
  <div id="inner_body">
    <div>
      Animate button below me!
    </div>
    <button class="bc" id="0" style="margin-top:250px">Botton A</button>  
    <button  class="bc" id="1" style="margin-top:250px">Botton B</button>
    <button class="bc" id="2">Botton C is below buton A and button B</button>
  </div>
</body>


$(document).on('click', '.bc', function() {
  var x = [];
  var y = [];
  //Saving original position
  for (var i = 0; i < 3; i = i + 1) {
    x[i] = $('#' + i + '').position().left;
    y[i] = $('#' + i + '').position().top;
  }

  //Locating all buttons with absolute position
  for (var i = 0; i < 3; i = i + 1) {
    $('#' + i + '').css({
      'position': 'absolute',
      'top': y[i] + 'px',
      'left': x[i] + 'px'
    })
  }

  //Hiding other buttons
  for (var i = 0; i < 3; i = i + 1) {
    if (i != this.id) {
      $('#' + i + '').remove();
    }
  }

  //Animating our buttons
  $(this).animate({
    left: 0,
    marginTop: 0,
    top:20 //added code here
  }, "slow");

});
```

Just add margin-top value to button A and B then add top:20 when animate.

Comment: This will work but I need a responsive page and there is a posiibility that button B will be located below button A in some screens or all 3 buttons will be located at the same line...

Comment: I see.. Mohamed-Yousef's answer would fit to your needs.